# Does this series converge uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

$$f(x)= \sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt{n}} e^{\frac{x}{n}} $$

(i) Show that for each $r > 0$, the series converges uniformly on $[−r,r]$

(ii) Is $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$? Justify your answer.

This is what I have done so far.

ANSWER:

(i) Let $\  f_n(x)= \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt{n}} e^{\frac{x}{n}}. $ Then $f= \sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty f_n .$ Since $\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges by the alternating series test $\sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty f_n(0)$ converges.

Applying [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) to $f'_n$, we have $||f'_n = \frac{(-1)^{n}}{{n}\sqrt{n}} e^{\frac{x}{n}}||\le \frac{1}{{n}\sqrt{n}} $ Therefore $f'_n$ converges uniformly on $[-r,r]$.

Therefore $f= \sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty f_n $ converges uniformly on $[-r,r]$

(ii) By the above $f(x)$ is differentiable.

Comment: You write both  $\;f= \sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty f_n\;$ and also $\;f= \sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty f_n(0)\;$ . The first one means, in my opinion, "for all $\;x\;$ (in some given domain), whereas the second one means "at one single point", so which one did you mean? Aso, the fact you have an alternating factor there isn't enough: what about $\;e^{x/n}\;$ , which also depends on $\;n\;$ ?

Comment: I guess your conclusion from the alternating series test is that $f(0) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(0)$ converges. Maybe it is just a typo, And for the second step, you made a small mistake: we should have $\| f_n' \|_{C([-r, r])} = n^{-3/2} e^{r/n}$, though the extra factor $e^{r/n}$ does not affect the argument. Except for these, your solution seems fine.

Comment: actually, for any $Re(\sigma) > 0$ : $$f_\sigma(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^\sigma} e^{z/n}$$
is an entire function.